# How to launch Chrome Advanced REST Client

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There's [this great REST client "extension" for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US), but the only way I can find to launch it is to go to the Chrome webstore!

It's listed as Enabled in my Chrome extensions.  Is there any local way to launch it?

[image: Advanced REST client Chrome extenstion]

Comment: <sigh>.  Downvoters and closer-voters: Why not just suggest migrating to whichever SE you think is more appropriate?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Chrome's Apps page should have the launch icon for Advanced REST client now that it's been installed.

URL: [chrome://apps/](http://:chrome://apps/)

Comment: If you are lucky, there is an "Apps" button with a colored 3x3 squares icon at the far left under the address bar

Answer (score 6):

From [Chrome Web Store Help](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/3060053?hl=en-GB):

> The Chrome App Launcher is no longer available on Windows, Mac or Linux. You can still open your Chrome Apps at chrome://apps.

Visit that URL. Click the icon for the app.

Answer (score 4):

Press "Details" on the Extensions page and create a shortcut

[image: How to create shortcut to Chrome extension]

Comment: Sadly this option doesn't seem to be available in modern Chrome versions (I'm on `Version 76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)`).

Comment: You can right click the icon from chrome://apps and create a shortcut from there.